# How does DataOutputStream convert values of a primitive type into a byte sequence?

Tags: java

`DataOutputStream`  has methods that convert values of a primitive
    type  into a byte sequence and then writes it to the underlying
    stream.

1. I was wondering how the conversion is done? Does the conversion not
   change the data stored in memory, but reinterpret the data of a
   primitive type as a byte sequence?
2. How can I simulate the conversion using `OutputStream` (e.g.
   `FileOutputStream`), for understanding `DataOutputStream` purpose? Here is my attempt:

   ```
   try(FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("myfile")){
       Random random = new Random();
       for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
           int tmp = random.nextInt();
           System.out.println(tmp);
           fout.write((byte[])tmp);  // error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to byte[]
       }
   } catch (IOException e){
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   ```

   but I receive at `(byte[])tmp`:

   ```
   error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to byte[]
   ```

   Why can't I cast `int` to `byte[]`?

   How shall I simulate the conversion?

   If I have an array of `int`, can I simulate the conversion using a single write method of `FileOutputStream`, instead of calling the write method once per element of the array?
   Thanks.

Comment: You can't cast an array of many objects to a single object!

Comment: Why can't I cast `int` to `byte[]`?

Comment: @Mark I can' t understand why  a `int` value can't be reinterpreted as `byte[]`. A `int` value is stored as a sequence of `byte` values.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're saying. You could either do it using the unsafe `Unsafe` class (which will be fast, but unsafe), or you can do it manually, but it will be slower. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how the conversion is done?

The simplest way is to read the code or Javadoc.

```
/**
 * Writes an <code>int</code> to the underlying output stream as four
 * bytes, high byte first. If no exception is thrown, the counter
 * <code>written</code> is incremented by <code>4</code>.
 *
 * @param      v   an <code>int</code> to be written.
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FilterOutputStream#out
 */
public final void writeInt(int v) throws IOException {
    out.write((v >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>>  0) & 0xFF);
    incCount(4);
}
```

> Does the conversion not change the data stored in memory, but reinterpret the data of a primitive type as a byte sequence?

No.

> So how shall I simulate the conversion?

You can't Java doesn't play those sort of tricks.

Note: You can do this using the `Unsafe` class, but you should avoid using it unless there is no other choice, because it's *unsafe*

> Where do you find " the code"?

You can find it in your IDE by clicking on the class or searching for it or you can google the source.

> Why can't I cast int to byte[]

There is no definition in Java what this would do. e.g. Should it be little endian or big endian? Note a `byte[]` is an object.

> Why does the code not mean that " the conversion does not change the data stored in memory, but reinterpret the data of a primitive type as a byte sequence?"

There is nothing the Java language which does this. There is low level library tools to do this but these have very specific use cases.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Where do you find " the code"?  (2) Why does the code not mean that "  the conversion does not change the data stored in memory, but reinterpret the data of a primitive type as a byte sequence?" (3) Why can't I cast `int` to `byte[]`?

Comment: @Ethan Imagine I have a box of apples (`byte[]`), and a single orange (`int`). They're not equal.

Comment: @Ethan 2) There is nothing in the Java language which does this.

Comment: I don't use IDE as of now, and can't find the source code on google.

Comment: @Ethan I suggest you use an IDE, it will save you a lot of time, for google I used https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dataoutputstream+writeint+source

Answer (score 0):

> How do I convert from `int` to `byte[]`?

Here's a piece of code that will do the conversion.

For later readers: scroll down for an example on converting an integer *array* to a byte array.

I will explain this code below.

```
static byte[] convertIntToByteArray(int x)
{
    // This assumes that int is 32-bit and has a size of 4 bytes
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    b[i] = ((x >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    b[i] = ((x >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    b[i] = ((x >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    b[i] = ((x >>>  0) & 0xFF);
    return b;
}
```

This code is an inefficient, but compatible way of splitting an `int` into `byte[]`. It manually uses bitmasks (like `DataOutputStream`) to manipulate each individual byte.

However, you are theoretically correct. An `int` is represented as individual bytes in memory, but software abstracts that for you.

Note: you could also use the `Unsafe` class for doing this. However, it's not exactly safe (read with sarcasm), and it would suffer easily from changes to Java's internal layout and platform differences. Also, Oracle has been trying to kill `Unsafe` for some time now. Hence, the method above is a slower, but very compatible method of handling it, and if you're not trying to write an emulator, then you should be able to get away with the performance loss.

## TL;DR

It's unnecessary to simulate the conversion. Just use `DataOutputStream`.

However, if you really want to simulate it, you can create a `byte[]` array and manually put the `ints` into it, then pass it to `ByteArrayOutputStream` like shown below. This essentially duplicates the existing functionality in Java, and I recommend using the built-in functions because they are pretty much guaranteed to be more optimized than yours. I have borrowed some of the code from Peter's answer above.

```
byte[] b = new byte[Integer.SIZE*4]; // large enough to hold 4 int vars (each int is guaranteed to be Integer.SIZE bytes)
int[] a = new int[4];
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < b.length; i+=Integer.SIZE, j++)
{
    b[i] = ((a[j] >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    b[i] = ((a[j] >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    b[i] = ((a[j] >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    b[i] = ((a[j] >>>  0) & 0xFF);
}
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("[your filename here]"); // WARNING: In real code, you need to handle the FileNotFoundException
fo.write(b);
fo.close();
```